# I want to know if this script is not dangerous python discord bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want use this script for my discord server but I don't know if this script is clear "It will not Ban members or remove the server". Because I don't know anything about Python

I don’t know if this kind of question is acceptable here or not

https://github.com/marcusbeckerman/role-saver-bot

Comment: When you add a bot to your server, you control which permissions it has.  Just don't give it the permissions to do things you don't want it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, this would be a good question for the code review community. The bot you linked is safe at the time of writing this answer. In python, you have a `main.py` that is what runs when the bot is started. If you CTRL+F in it and try to find a word named ban or kick it shows what it does. From looking in the file it does not ban or kick any members.

Comment: There are some hardcoded (writed in code) lines at the end but I'm not an expert in discord bots but I suggest you to review this harcoded lines before adding the bot, or testing it in a controlled environment. The repository don't have many stars or watchers, these are indicators of people using it.

Comment: @Ed.Kenbers those lines are fine I see